# C language : Why my program exits when I press '+' after the printf statement ("enter an operator")?

Tags: c

The code has no errors but it stops when I press `+` in compiler. Anyone knows why this happens?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    //Local declaration
    char op;
    int n1,n2;

    //Statements
    printf("Enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
    printf("Enter an operator");
    scanf("%c",&op);
    if (op =='+')
        printf("Addition is %d",n1+n2);
    else if (op =='-')
        printf("Subtraction is %d",n1-n2);
    else if (op =='*')
        printf("Multiplication is %d",n1*n2);
    else if (op =='/')
        printf("Division is %d",n1/n2);
    else if (op =='%')
        printf("Modulo is %d",n1%n2);
}
```

output:

```
   Enter Two numbers:10 20
   Enter an operator: +
```

Then exits.

The execution stops when pressed `+`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because of the `newline` character, which your press after entering 2 numbers.

The newline character stays inside the input buffer.

**Solution 1:** Use `getchar()` till the newline character is read as input and then scan the `op`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{       //Local declaration
        char op;
        int n1,n2;
        //Statements
        printf("Enter two numbers");
        scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
        printf("Enter an operator");

        while ( getchar() != '\n' && getchar()!=EOF); // do nothing 

        scanf("%c",&op);
        if(op =='+')
        printf("Addition is %d",n1+n2);
        else if(op =='-')
        printf("Subtraction is %d",n1-n2);
        else if(op =='*')
        printf("Multiplication is %d",n1*n2);
        else if(op =='/')
        printf("Division is %d",n1/n2);
        else if(op =='%')
        printf("Modulo is %d",n1%n2);
 }
```

**Solution 2:** Use a space before `%c` in scanf() to absorb the whitespace and a more clean approach. Thanks to **@dbush** for suggesting this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{       //Local declaration
        char op;
        int n1,n2;
        //Statements
        printf("Enter two numbers");
        scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
        printf("Enter an operator"); 
        scanf(" %c",&op);
        if(op =='+')
        printf("Addition is %d",n1+n2);
        else if(op =='-')
        printf("Subtraction is %d",n1-n2);
        else if(op =='*')
        printf("Multiplication is %d",n1*n2);
        else if(op =='/')
        printf("Division is %d",n1/n2);
        else if(op =='%')
        printf("Modulo is %d",n1%n2);
}
```

Comment: This works, but a cleaner way would be to put a space before `%c` to absorb the whitespace, i.e. ...... `scanf(" %c",&op);`

Comment: @dbush, made the changes. Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `scanf` it leaves the new-line from the initial input in the input stream. You need to consume that new-line character before calling `scanf` again, using something like `fgetc`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{       //Local declaration
        char op, nl;
        int n1,n2;
        //Statements
        printf("Enter two numbers");
        scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
        nl = fgetc(stdin);
        printf("Enter an operator");
        scanf("%c",&op);
        nl = fgetc(stdin);
        if(op =='+')
        printf("Addition is %d",n1+n2);
        else if(op =='-')
        printf("Subtraction is %d",n1-n2);
        else if(op =='*')
        printf("Multiplication is %d",n1*n2);
        else if(op =='/')
        printf("Division is %d",n1/n2);
        else if(op =='%')
        printf("Modulo is %d",n1%n2);
 }
```